# While loop to produce multiple lists and plots creates memory error

Tags: python, loops, memory-management, out-of-memory

I have the following code, where I want to plot temperature against iteration number or a solar input in a scatter graph.

I keep getting a memory error, which I think is due to the size of the lists this code creates. Is there any way I can store the outputs elsewhere or breakdown this loop so the output isn't so large? I am currently using python 3 64 bit.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#define constants


LRange = [1290, 1310] #W/m2
Episilon = 1 #no units
Sigma = 5.67E-08 #Wm-2K-4

#L, albedo, nIters = input("").split()
#L, albedo, nIters = [float(L), float(albedo), int(nIters) ]

L = 1250
albedo = 0.15
nIters = 1

Ice_Lat_m = 1.5
Ice_lat_c = -322.5
Alb_m = -0.01
Alb_c = 2.8

plotType = "iterDown" #"L", "iterUp", "iterDown"

x = []
y = []

while L < LRange[1]+1:
    for iter in range(nIters):
        T = L * ( 1- albedo) / 4 * Sigma
        T = T ** (0.25)
        albedo = Alb_m * T +Alb_c
        albedo = min(albedo, 0.65)
        albedo = max(albedo, 0.15)
        lat_ice = Ice_Lat_m * T + Ice_lat_c
        lat_ice = min(lat_ice, 90)
        lat_ice = max(lat_ice, 0)
       # if plotType is "iter" or plotType is "iterup":
            #x.append(iter)
           # y.append(T)
   # if plotType is "iter" or plotType is "iterup":
       # x.append(np.nan)
        #y.append(np.nan)
  #  if plotType is "L":
       # x.append(L)
       # x.append(T)
    L = L + 10

while L > LRange[0]-1:
    for iter in range(nIters):
        T = L * ( 1- albedo) / 4 * Sigma
        T = T ** (0.25)
        albedo = Alb_m * T +Alb_c
        albedo = min(albedo, 0.65)
        albedo = max(albedo, 0.15)
        lat_ice = Ice_Lat_m * T + Ice_lat_c
        lat_ice = min(lat_ice, 90)
        lat_ice = max(lat_ice, 0)
        #if plotType is "iter" or plotType is "iterdown":
            #x.append(iter)
            #y.append(T)
   # if plotType is "iter" or plotType is "iterdown":
       # x.append(np.nan)
        y.append(np.nan)
    #if plotType is "L":
        #x.append(L)
        #x.append(T)
    L = L + 10

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

print(T, albedo)
```

Comment: please show at which line the error occurs? and show error message.

Comment: Hey I have managed to fix this. The issue was the edition of python I was using.